# How to show that an extension is integral?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I\subset R[x]$ an ideal in $R[x]$ that contains a monic  polynomial. I want to show that $R/(R\cap I)\rightarrow R[x]/I$ is an integral extension.

This is the case, if $R[x]/I$ is finitely generated as an $R/(R\cap I)$-module but I am stuck at that point.

I can show, that since $f$ in monic, $R[x]/(f)$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Thus we have $R\twoheadrightarrow R[x]/(f)\twoheadrightarrow R[x]/I$ so that $R[x]/I$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

Can I conclude from the above fact, that $R[x]/I$ is finitely generated as an $R/(R\cap I)$-module?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $(R \cap I)R[x] \subseteq I$, so by the third isomorphism theorem,

$$R[x]/I \cong (R[x]/(R \cap I)R[x])/(I/(R \cap I)R[x]) = S[x]/IS[x],$$

where $S = R/(R \cap I)$. Now since $I$ contains a monic polynomial $f$, the image of $f$ in $S[x]$ (obtained by reducing coefficients mod $R \cap I$) will remain monic, so $x \in S[x]/IS[x]$ is integral over $S$ (as $f$ is an equation of integrality). This shows that $S \subseteq S[x]/IS[x]$ is a module-finite, hence integral, extension.